# Automatic differentiation-Reverse mode

Tags: calculus, derivatives, algorithms

I am trying to understand very basics material and a bit confused about steps.

If we have function $z=f(x_1,x_1)=x_1x_2+sinx_1=w_1w_2+sinw_1=w_1+w_4=w_5$ we need  fix the dependent variable to be differentiated and computes the derivative with respect to each sub-expression recursively, according to chain rule we have -

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dw_1}\frac{dw_1}{dx}=(\frac{dy}{dw_2}\frac{dw_2}{dw_1})\frac{dw_1}{dx}=(((\frac{dy}{dw_4}\frac{dw_4}{dw_3})\frac{dw_3}{dw_2})\frac{dw_2}{dw_1})\frac{dw_1}{dx}=((((\frac{dy}{dw_5}\frac{dw_5}{dw_4})\frac{dw_4}{dw_3})\frac{dw_3}{dw_2})\frac{dw_2}{dw_1})\frac{dw_1}{dx}$

$w_1=x_1, w_2=x_2$

$\bar w=\frac{dy}{dw}$

Then I have the next calculation-

1) $\bar f =\bar w_5 = 1 $ seed

2) $\bar w_4=$$\bar w_5$$\frac{dw_5}{dw_4}=$$\bar w_5 *1$

2) $\bar w_3=$$\bar w_5$$\frac{dw_5}{dw_3}=$$\bar w_5 *1$

3) $\bar w_2=$$\bar w_3$$\frac{dw_3}{dw_2}=$$\bar w_3 w_1$

I don't really see how we obtained these steps from the chain.

Can somebody explain it more clearly, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example,
$$ \eqalign{w_1 &= x_1\cr
            w_2 &= x_2\cr
            w_3 &= w_1 w_2\cr
            w_4 &= \sin(w_1)\cr
            z = w_5 &= w_3 + w_4\cr}$$

EDIT: In reverse mode, you work with the adjoints $\overline{w_j} = \partial z/\partial w_j$, using the chain rule.  For each node in the computation graph, you compute this using the  nodes to which it is an input.

You start with $\overline{w}_5 = 1$.

$w_4$ is an input only to $w_5$, through the equation $w_5 =w_3 + w_4$, so
$$\overline{w_4} = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w_5} \dfrac{\partial w_5}{\partial w_4} = \overline{w_5} $$
Similarly, $\overline{w_3} = \overline{w_5} $.
$w_2$ is an input to $w_3$ through $w_3 = w_1 w_2$, so
$$ \overline{w_2} = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w_3} \dfrac{\partial w_3}{\partial w_2} = \overline{w_3} w_1$$
$w_1$ is an input to both $w_3$ and $w_4$, so
$$ \overline{w_1} 
=   \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w_3} \dfrac{\partial w_3}{\partial w_1} + \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w_4} \dfrac{\partial w_4}{\partial w_1} = \overline{w_3} w_2 + \overline{w_4} \cos(w_1)$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help. I just want to ask- Do we always have addition for the last step? I tried to do another equations and for $f(x)=(x+x^2)^2$ for the last step I have x as input for $\bar w_2$ and $\bar w_3$ so if $w_1=x$ for w3 $\bar w_1^a=$$\bar w_3 \frac {dw_3}{dw_1}=2w_3(1+2w_1)=2w_3+4w_3w_1$ and for w2  $\bar w_1^b=$$\bar w_2 \frac {dw_2}{dw_1}=2w_3+2w_1=4w_3w_1$ So if we compute just $\bar w_1^a=$ we will receive $\bar x$ and I don't need $\bar w_1^b$ to compute it - seems to be wrong

Comment: No, of course addition doesn't have to be last.  For your example $f(x) = (x + x^2)^2$, written $w_1 = x$, $w_2 = w_1^2$, $w_3 = w_1 + w_2$. $w_4 = w_3^2$, I get $\overline{w_4} = 1$, $\overline{w_3} = 2 \overline{w_4} w_3$, $\overline{w_2} = \overline{w_3}$, $\overline{w_1} = 2 \overline{w_2} w_1 + \overline{w_3}$.

Comment: Yes, I have absolutely the same, but this computation for $\bar w_1$ is graph path from X1 to W3 (to + operation), but what about path from X1 to W2? Sorry for disturbing you, but I can't get when we compute only one path when we need to add both parts of X1 and when we should do multiplication?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  In the equation for $\overline{w_i}$ you will have a term involving $\overline{w_j}$ whenever the definition of $w_j$ contains a $w_i$.  Here $w_1$ occurs in $w_2$ and $w_3$, so the equation for $\overline{w_1}$ has a term for $\overline{w_2}$ and a term for $\overline{w_3}$.

Comment: For  term for $\bar w_2$ we have $\bar w_2$$\frac {dw_2}{dw_1}$$=2w_3+2w_1=4w_3w_1$ and for term  $\bar w_3$ I have received $\bar w_3$$\frac{dw_3}{dw_1}=2w_3 \frac{d(w_1+w_2)}{dw_1}=2w_3(1+2w_1)=2w_3+4w_3w_1$, then i need to do addition to calculate $\bar w_1$ and I have  $\bar w_1=$ $4w_3w_1+2w_3+4w_3w_1$ which is not right.... but your result is absolutely right - here I am confused